# Fill mesh gaps with almost like a clay?

Tags: boolean-modifier, smooth

I combined 2 seperate meshes, 1 of my teeth and 1 of my skull, however, they came from 2 different sources. Is there a way I can take a cube and boolean it to fill the gaps created by the teeth?? In a normal mouth it is obviously connected.

Here is what it looks like without any filling:
[image]

[image]

And here is the piece I added to try and boolean a fitment of some kind... I sculpted a bit to see if it helped but it really did not.

[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance for your time!! :)

Comment: I would look into using the Remesh modifier, which will attempt to voxelize and then recreate geometry of all convex meshes in within an object. Your mesh looks extremely messy so it might not give the best results, but that's probably going to give you better results than this solution.